# Matplotlib: the problem is that len(xy) or (xy) is not acceptable

Tags: python

It is part of long python code that I got the errors:

```
m = Basemap(...)
lons = ...
lats = ...
x, y = m( lons, lats )
xy = zip(x,y)
print('xy=',xy)
poly = Polygon( xy, facecolor='none', edgecolor=linecolor )

output:
..\site-packages\matplotlib\patches.py", line 1070, in set_xy
    if len(xy) and (xy[0] != xy[-1]).any():
TypeError: len() of unsized object
```

Matplotlib: the problem is that len(xy) or (xy) is not acceptable.

Because that codes include many variables,
The short reproducible codes that I can make
(by printing (x,y)):

```
x,y= [105, 98, 98, 105], [-5, -5, 6, 6]
xy = zip(x,y)
len(xy) 
error: TypeError: object of type 'zip' has no len()
```

Any suggestions to fix this problem ?

Comment: when I use xy.size instead of len(xy) in the matplotlib the error is:

Comment: if xy.size and (xy[0] != xy[-1]) ...
IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 0-dimensional, but 1 were indexed

Comment: `xy = list(zip(x, y))` ?

Comment: `xy` is a `zip` object, as the error states, `zip` objects do not have a length.

Comment: So, zip object not matchs with np.asarray() 
What np..... that matches with zip object?

Comment: Here matplotlib codes that cause the errors as xy is an zip object and not accepted by len():
xy = np.asarray(xy)
        if self._closed:
            if len(xy) and (xy[0] != xy[-1]).any():
                xy = np.concatenate([xy, [xy[0]]])
        else:
            if len(xy) > 2 and (xy[0] == xy[-1]).all():
                xy = xy[:-1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `zip` function returns a special type of zip object, not a list. To get the list type, you need to do `list(zip(x, y))`

```py
>>> x,y= [105, 98, 98, 105], [-5, -5, 6, 6]
>>> xy = zip(x,y)
>>> xy
<zip object at 0x100eaf280>
>>> xy = list(zip(x, y))
>>> xy
[(105, -5), (98, -5), (98, 6), (105, 6)]
>>> len(xy)
4
```